# Saving data from a Fragment to Room creates an infinite loop

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-room, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am attempting to save some date in a table using Room Database. Those data are collected in some fragments, following the recommendations that we should use fragments instead of activities. Because of some different layouts based on the user's choices, I end up having to collect data from a parent fragment and its child.

The problem is the fact that, at the time the data have to be inserted on my table, the app freezes.

Let me explain properly how I am handling the data so far, since that might be the reason of my troubles.

First, since I have to handle data from two different Fragments, I am following the developer's guide and using a ViewModel to share data from one to another (and, based on my tests, that is working fine so far).

```java
public class ViewModelFragments extends ViewModel {
// saveAttemptWaterFountain is used as an indicator that the user clicked on the save button
// and the app should start to save the data entered by the user
    private final MutableLiveData<Integer> saveAttemptWaterFountain = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void saveAttemptTestWaterFountain(Integer integer) {
        saveAttemptWaterFountain.setValue(integer);
    }

    public LiveData<Integer> getSaveAttempt() {
        return saveAttemptWaterFountain;
    }

// fountainBundle is a bundle where I save all the data that comes from the fragment. Since it is
//different types of data from different fragments, I create a bundle to wrap all of it.
    private final MutableLiveData<Bundle> fountainBundle = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void setFountainBundle(Bundle bundle) {
        fountainBundle.setValue(bundle);
    }

    public LiveData<Bundle> getFountainBundle() {
        return fountainBundle;
    }
}
```

In my parent fragment I created a clickListener that watches when the user clicks on the save button. This Listener is currently written as follows:

```java
        saveWaterFountain.setOnClickListener(v -> {
// I create an observer that awaits for a change in the saved bundle to be activated
            modelFragments.getFountainBundle().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), bundle -> {
//verifyWaterFountainerrors is a method only to verify if some fields are empty
                if (verifyWaterFountainErrors()) {
//Verification if tha observed bundle has data
                    if (bundle != null) {
//Here I am creating an object of the same type as my Entity (where I will save this data)
                        newFountain = createFountain(bundle, chosenFountain);
                    }
                }
            });
//I put up this method to fire off the "saving action" inside the child fragment
            modelFragments.saveAttemptTestWaterFountain(1);
//Insertion of the object in my Room Database
            ViewModelEntry.insertWaterFountain(newFountain);
//Nullifying the bundle at the shared ViewModel
            modelFragments.setFountainBundle(null);
        });
```

As showed in the parent fragment, I use the `modelFragments.saveAttemptTestWaterFountain(1);` to fire off the saving process in the child fragment. This was written as follows:

```java
// Observable method that awaits the parent fragment to send a signal to start
        modelFragments.getSaveAttempt().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), saveAttempt -> {
//Method that checks if there is no empty fields
            if(hasNoEmptyFields()) {
//Process of gathering data from the fragment and wrapping it inside a Bundle
                Bundle spoutData = new Bundle();
                spoutData.putInt(ALLOW_FRONTAL, getCheckedIndex(allowFrontalApprox));
                spoutData.putDouble(HIGHEST_SPOUT, Double.parseDouble(Objects.requireNonNull(highestSpoutValue.getText()).toString()));
                spoutData.putDouble(LOWEST_SPOUT, Double.parseDouble(Objects.requireNonNull(lowestSpoutValue.getText()).toString()));
                spoutData.putDouble(FREE_SPACE_SPOUT, Double.parseDouble(Objects.requireNonNull(freeSpaceSpoutValue.getText()).toString()));
                modelFragments.setFountainBundle(spoutData);
            }
// "clearing" the trigger to allow the user to click on the save button again.
            modelFragments.saveAttemptTestWaterFountain(0);
        });
```

If I run the code as shown above, the data is not saved on the table and mu "Run" log looks like this:

```java
V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 5238.
V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 5238.
V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 5238.
I/X: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7ec9f08c00 (DropDownListView) with handle 0x7ec5b06500
I/X: Background concurrent copying GC freed 818907(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 19MB/39MB, paused 132us total 280.787ms
I/X: Background concurrent copying GC freed 920672(24MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 22MB/44MB, paused 120us total 158.862ms
I/X: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1072356(27MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 24MB/48MB, paused 121us total 197.570ms
I/X: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1133503(29MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 41% free, 34MB/58MB, paused 121us total 247.091ms
...
```

However, if I make a change to my observable in the parent fragment, putting my insertion method INSIDE the observable, then the info **is** saved on my table. However, it enters in an infinite loop, saving line after line of the same data. In this case, my "Run" log looks like:

```java
        saveWaterFountain.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            modelFragments.getFountainBundle().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), bundle -> {
                if (verifyWaterFountainErrors()) {
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        newFountain = createFountain(bundle, chosenFountain);
// Same method as shown above, but now the insertion method is inside the observable
                        ViewModelEntry.insertWaterFountain(newFountain);
                    }
                }
            });
            modelFragments.saveAttemptTestWaterFountain(1);
            modelFragments.setFountainBundle(null);
        });
```

```java
V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 5927.
I/X: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7e4ecaf700 (DropDownListView) with handle 0x7e4f356da0
V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 5927.
I/X: Background concurrent copying GC freed 441637(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 18MB/37MB, paused 416us total 124.037ms
I/X: Background concurrent copying GC freed 604397(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 42% free, 32MB/56MB, paused 125us total 211.991ms
V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 5927.
I/X: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/X: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/X: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
```

This is a picture provin that this method at least saves the data:

[image: saved data into database]

My question is: What is causing this infinite loop? Is it possible to fix such thing?

And, a more subjective question would be: The way I'm handling this data is acceptable by development standards?

Comment: 1.) MutableLiveData should not contain *mutable* types 2.) LiveData.observe is supposed to happen explicitly and only inside `Fragment.onViewCreated` and `Activity.onCreate`, it should never happen as the side-effect of a button click etc

Comment: @EpicPandaForce 1) So I should use primitive objects or immutable classes/objects? But isn't `MutableLiveData` used exactly to observe changes in data? If I use a immutable type, wouldn't it defeat the purpose of using the `MutableLiveData`? 2) In this case I should put in my button click just the change of "status" and create the observer outside it?

Comment: 1.) either works; yes and that is exactly why they should be immutable; no 2.) the observer must be created in the callback and not as a result of events, so probably